# jQuery remove the nearlest P tag

Tags: jquery

i have this jquery code

```
$("#eioShowLink").on('click',function(){
        $("#ioEditRelatedConcepts").html('');
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Ontology/getRelatedConceptsAndRelations/"+conceptName+"/TRUE", function(data){
            var concepts = data[0];
            var relations = data[1];
            for(var i = 0 ; i < concepts.length ; i++){
                (function(currentConcept, currentRelation) {
                    $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/InformationObject/getIOsForConcept/"+currentConcept+"/TRUE" , function(data1){
                        var IOS = '';
                        IOS +="<option>Select IO</option>";
                        for(var j=0;j<data1.length;j++){
                            IOS+="<option>"+data1[j]+"</option>";
                        }
                        $("#ioEditRelatedConcepts").append('<p>\n\
              connect to\n\
              <span class="ioAddConcept">'+ currentConcept +'</span>\n\
              with\n\
              <span class="ioAddRelation">'+ currentRelation +'</span>\n\
              <select name ="concetedIOs[]" class="TypeSelector">'+IOS+'</select>\n\
              <span class="errorMessage"></span>\n\
              <a href="#" class="removeA" id="eioRemoveIO">remove</a>\n\
              </p>\n\
              <p>');
                    });
                })(concepts[i], relations[i]);
            }
        });

    });
```

it works good, now i want when press the link "eioremoveIO" i want to remove the nearlest P tag, so i tried this

```
$("#editOnePlace").on('click','#eioRemoveIO',function(){
    $(this).closest('p').remove();
});
```

but nothing happen when pressing, it seems that it doesn't even fired, would you tell me what am i doing wrong?

#### edit

`#editOnePlace"` is the id of my div(doesn't appear here)

#### edit

the html

```
 <li>
                <p>
                    <label>Concepts</label>
                    <a href="#" class="smallLink" id="eioShowLink">Show Concepts</a>
                </p>
                <div id="ioEditRelatedConcepts">
                </div>
            </li>
```

Comment: @yunzen check the edit please , i added the html code

Comment: Looks to me like your code is creating invalid html, specifically the outer loop is appending multiple elements with `id="eioRemoveIO"` - id is supposed to be unique. Try changing that to use `class="eioRemoveIO"` and update your other code to select by class rather than id: `$("#editOnePlace").on('click','.eioRemoveIO',function(){...`

Comment: With this code you are assuming `#editOnePlace` is a descendant of the `p` that you want to delete. So you are trying to delete link itself too. Is this what you want?

Comment: thank you all Adil gives me the right code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery function closest gives the closest ancestor You can use prev/next to get previous/next  sibling.

```
$("#editOnePlace").on('click','#eioRemoveIO',function(){
    $(this).prev('p').remove();
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work, and i tried to alter insite the function ,but doesn't alter any thing

Comment: Could you put complete html that is used in the current scenario?

Comment: It happens to us that we miss something at first sight :) Thanks for being kind.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using a recent version of jQuery:

```
 $('#eioRemoveIO').live('click',function(){     
    $(this).closest('p').remove();
 });
```